# Why COALESCE return NULL instead of value I need?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, coalesce

From the table `tblQuoteStatusChangeLog` I need to check if column `NewQuoteStatusID` has one of those values (2, 25 or 202), and pick the earliest TimeStamp. 
So if it has value `2`, then pick up the `TimeStamp`, if it doesnt have value `2` then check if there is `25` and pick up corresponding `TimeStamp`, and if its not then check for `202` and pick up proper stamp.

So from `tblQuoteStatusChangeLog` I need to pick up first row with StatusID 202, because its the only that falls under condition.

[image]

So I have this query:

```
SELECT  
      (SELECT        TOP (1) Timestamp
                    FROM            tblQuoteStatusChangeLog
                    WHERE        NewQuoteStatusID = COALESCE (2,25,202)  AND ControlNo = tblQuotes.ControlNo
                    ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) as DateQuoted
FROM tblQuotes
INNER JOIN tblMaxQuoteIDs ON tblQuotes.QuoteID = tblMaxQuoteIDs.MaxQuoteID
where tblQuotes.ControlNo = 50065
```

But for some reason I got `NULL` value as a result

[image]

What am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `coalesce()` is the function that you want.  `coalesce(2, 25, 2002)` returns the first non-`NULL` value, which is always "2".  Your sample data doesn't have the value "2", so that is why the subquery returns `NULL`.

I think you might want `IN`:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP (1) Timestamp
        FROM tblQuoteStatusChangeLog
        WHERE NewQuoteStatusID IN (2, 25, 202) AND
              ControlNo = tblQuotes.ControlNo
        ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
       )
```

Comment: Oh! its only for non-`NULL`. Got it. 
Thanks. 
So then lets say if I'll have both values 2 and 25. What `IN` will pick up? The first one, which is 2 or the second one which is 25?

Comment: @Oleg . . . It will pick all that match.  The `ORDER BY` and `TOP` determine which is returned.